# Find a particular array of objects using Mongoose and just only get all the objects inside it

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Imagine that I have this collection:

```
{
  "_id": "2020 Standings",
  "DriversChampionship": [
    {
      "_id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc010475",
      "driverName": "Lewis Hamilton",
      "driverTeam": "Mercedes AMG",
      "driverPts": "230"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc010476",
      "driverName": "Sebastian Vettel",
      "driverTeam": "Ferrari",
      "driverPts": "161"
    }
  ],
  "ConstructorsChampionship": [
    {
      "_id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc010489",
      "teamName": "Mercedes AMG",
      "teamPts": "230"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc01048a",
      "teamName": "Ferrari",
      "teamPts": "161"
    }
  ]
}
```

And inside the Routes folder I got this for the GET request

```
router.route("api/standings/:arrayName")
    .get(getStandingsArray);
```

**So, how can I can find with Mongoose, and then send a res.json, with just the array that matches the `:arrayName?`**

Let me explain better with an example:

I type the following route `http://localhost:4000/api/standings/DriversChampionship`

then in my controller I ask for the `:arrayName` with...

```
const arrayName = req.params.arrayName

// arrayName = DriversChampionship
```

in order to later print this particular array of objects using `modelName.find()`...

```
"DriversChampionship": [
    {
      "_id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc010475",
      "driverName": "Lewis Hamilton",
      "driverTeam": "Mercedes AMG",
      "driverPts": "230"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc010476",
      "driverName": "Sebastian Vettel",
      "driverTeam": "Ferrari",
      "driverPts": "161"
    }
  ]
```

I was trying to figure it out but I don't really know how to tell Mongoose that.

Any idea?

Let me know if you don't understand any of my explanations

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the field you want *( which is 'DriversChampionship' in your example )* by using select, here's an example:

```
var query = modelName.find({}).select('DriversChampionship -_id');
```

to make it dynamic :

```
const arrayName = req.params.arrayName
var query = modelName.find({}).select(`${arrayName} -_id`);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Can I ask why you use -_id after the array name?

Comment: because the _id field is always present unless we exclude it